# Geometry via Conics

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to find an elementary geometry problem which is difficult to prove by using triangles and circles. However, if we were to construct some conic section, and use the properties of conics, then we would elegantly find the proof. I have looked at books and never really came across a specific example that illustrates this. Not even contest geometry math problems ever ask questions on the conics. Is there such an example?

Comment: you might like  this book, he shows several projective geometry problems with a synthetic approach https://www.google.com/books/edition/100_Great_Problems_of_Elementary_Mathema/C5iH2dczNG4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Given the definition of ellipse as the loci of points whose sum of distances from two focal points is constant, prove that a ray of light passing through one of those focal points and hitting the inner side of an elliptic mirror will pass through the other focal point.

Comment: @Saeed That is a nice property, however, it does not address the main question, i.e. solve a geometry problem by constructing a conic. Your exercise is an exercise directly in conics, not a construction of one.

Comment: Could this be useful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526373/is-it-possible-to-only-measure-things-on-one-axis-yet-be-able-to-derive-a-locat/3527099#3527099

Comment: Another case where a hyperbola is useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369230/maximum-of-difference-of-two-side-in-a-tetrahedron/3369420#3369420

Comment: Other examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217480/path-traced-by-the-point-of-closest-approach-to-the-origin-of-a-circle-with-two/4217526#4217526 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967331/i-have-two-circles-and-a-point/1967440#1967440

Comment: Hyperbolas can be used to find the solutions of Apollonius's problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius#Intersecting_hyperbolas

Comment: One real world application that I know from both a book and lecture by Jürgen Richter-Gebert is this: given a photo of a skyline or landscape, determine from where it was taken. A conic is the locus from which four given points appear under a certain cross ratio. So pick four landmarks, and measure their cross ratio on the photo. Identify these landmarks on a map and you get one specific conic through these points. Find a fifth landmark and you get 4 more conics, all of which intersect at the point where the camera was when the photo was taken. Not sure this would be considered elementary.